# Thread Pool in MariaDB vs Innodb thread and pool settings

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, innodb, mariadb, pool

Until I started using Thread Pool in MariaDB,  my.cnf file was having the settings below to keep the SQL server stable.

```
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size
innodb_buffer_pool_size
innodb_commit_concurrency
innodb_write_io_threads
innodb_read_io_threads
innodb_thread_concurrency
innodb_sort_buffer_size
```

After I have learned that MariaDB supports Thread Pool feature for free then I added 
thread_handling=pool-of-threads 
line in my.cnf, I restarted SQL server and everything seems cool, now I was wondering that

1. Do the Innodb settings above still count?
2. Does the Thread Pool in MariaDB manages number of threads, memory allocations, concurrencies etc?
3. Finally, after started using Thread Pool in MariaDB, should I still keep these innodb settings or should I delete them?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. Do the Innodb settings above still count?

Yes, they still count. the Threadpool does not know about innodb specifics. It does not even know if you run a "SELECT 1" or a DML statement on Innodb table. Everything is an opaque query. Threadpool knows though whether a thread is running or waiting, and tries to keep count of running threads at number of CPUs (or, thread-pool-size if you're on Unix) . The only setting that does **not** count with threadpool is *thread-cache-size*

2. Does the Thread Pool in MariaDB manages number of threads, memory allocations, concurrencies etc?

Number of threads, concurrency. Not the memory allocation.

3. Finally, after started using Thread Pool in MariaDB, should I still keep these innodb settings or should I delete them?

Don't delete them all. Threadpool does not manage buffer sizes, so these one is pretty important to keep.  However you can expriment whether to keep or remove *innodb-thread-concurrency,* and *innodb-commit-concurrency*, as those might  be obsoleted by threadpool (they still can be efficient on heavy write workloads though)

Answer (score 0):

The settings...

- innodb_additional_mem_pool_size -- deprecated in MySQL and removed in 5.7; possibly still in use in MariaDB; not a very important setting.
- innodb_buffer_pool_size -- *ABSOLUTELY*. This is still the most important setting; keep it!
- The rest -- keep.